# Python selenium script packaging

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

just searched google but could not find answer, i want to know if it's possible to package python script with selenium into EXE file.
i'm asking this question because selenium needs webdriver.Chrome location to work properly. i created external TXT file and put my webdriver location there and told python to take loc from there but it didn't work. thanks in advance!

Comment: you can just put webdriver.exe to the same folder with your .exe

Comment: See if this helps you: https://www.zacoding.com/en/post/python-selenium-to-exe/